# GIT keep asking for merging even though it's nothing to merge

Tags: git

I use git to store my wordpress

then I update something via "**wordpress admin editor**"

then update something in local and wants to push it

and I got this [image]

I have stash and merge it and got this

[image]

why is it?

Comment: Please list your commands on doing this.

Answer (score 1):

When you updated something in admin editor, you changed you local files (files in working directory). To push changes to server, you need to commit them to your local repo, then fetch changes from server, merge them, and push.
When you stashed your changes, you basically canceled them in your working directory. (to get them back, you can run `git stash apply`). This is why when you merge origin/master, there is nothing to merge.

So, you should:

1. change something in admin editor
2. git add -A 

   (adds changes to index)
3. git commit -m "Commit message"

   (commit to local repo)
4. git fetch origin

   (fetch changes from origin)
5. git merge origin/master

   (merge)
6. git push origin master

   (push)